# Django tests fail on Postgresql (8.4) - Flushing DB causes error

Tags: python, database, django, postgresql, testing

I'm dealing with a very annoying problem when trying to run DJ tests for a project on PostgreSQL backend. It starts running the tests and when the first DB flush should happen it fails with a strange error:

```
..Error: Database dbname couldn't be flushed. Possible reasons:
  * The database isn't running or isn't configured correctly.
  * At least one of the expected database tables doesn't exist.
  * The SQL was invalid.
Hint: Look at the output of 'django-admin.py sqlflush'. That's the SQL this command wasn't able to run.
The full error: cannot TRUNCATE "table_name" because it has pending trigger events
```

If I run the output of sqlflush through pgAdmin, it runs just fine.

Any ideas are welcome for possible causes.

**Update:**

OK, looks like this is not actually a problem from Django, instead it's related to the test runner from *djangosanetesting*. With default DJ test runner or *django-nose* test runner it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, looks like this is not actually a problem from Django, instead it's related to the test runner from *djangosanetesting*, for which flushing seems to be broken in some way.
For now I don't have a better solution than just using *django-nose* test runner.

Comment: Would you mind filing bug report @ https://github.com/Almad/django-sane-testing/issues ? I didn't knew about the issue...